# trying to remove duplicate entries in database but getting nil id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using a rails find_by_sql query to find duplicate entries but I am having a terrible time removing them because the query returns an array with ids listed as nil.

```rb
LogEntry.find_by_sql("SELECT date, athlete_id, count(*) as qty FROM log_entries GROUP BY date, athlete_id HAVING count(*)> 1")
```

This returns the following array:

```rb
[#<LogEntry id: nil, date: "2016-06-12", athlete_id: 49>, #<LogEntry id: nil, date: "2015-09-05", athlete_id: nil>, #<LogEntry id: nil, date: "2015-09-06", athlete_id: nil>, #<LogEntry id: nil, date: "2019-05-02", athlete_id: nil>]
```

When I try and add `.each(&:destroy)` it does not manage to destroy it because as you can see the ids are listed as nil. What I don't get is how this is even possible? The entries should be able to exist in the table without ids. Is there a problem with my sql query?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write that query as `LogEntry.select('id, date, athlete_id, count(*) AS qty').group(:date, :athlete_id).having('count(*)> 1')`.

Comment: You cannot select the id to find duplicates in this fashion. This would have to be multiple queries becuase `id` will make the row unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated answer after @engineersmnky's comment (thanks, missed the grouping).

In order to remove duplicates, you'll have to get the IDs of the duplicate rows. For each duplicate, you'll want N - 1 IDs as one should be left behind.

To get all IDs for each group that has more than one (and thus has duplicates):

```
SELECT array_agg(id) FROM log_entries GROUP BY date, athlete_id HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Let's leave out the first ID in each group:

```
SELECT (array_agg(id))[2:] FROM log_entries GROUP BY date, athlete_id HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Next, we need to unnest them so that we get a list of just the IDs we want to delete:

```
SELECT unnest((array_agg(id))[2:]) FROM log_entries GROUP BY date, athlete_id HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Now, in order to load these in Rails, a simple `.where(..)` suffices where the ID is in the above constructed result set:

```
LogEntry.where('id IN (SELECT unnest((array_agg(id))[2:]) FROM log_entries GROUP BY date, athlete_id HAVING count(*) > 1)')
```

---

Original answer:

Your `SELECT` is not selecting the `id`. Add `id` to your query and it should work:

```
LogEntry.find_by_sql("SELECT id, date, athlete_id, count(*) as qty FROM log_entries GROUP BY date, athlete_id HAVING count(*)> 1")
```

Comment: `id` will then have to be part of an aggregate function which defeats the point.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer accordingly.